# Terraform code for creating AWS EC2 instances with volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create two EC2 instances on AWS with the following features:

- Instance: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type
- Type: ami for 64-bit x86 us-east-1 region  ami-0747bdcabd34c712a (64-bit x86)
- Type: 2 processors, 8 GB Memory, Up to 10 Gigabit Network, m5a type m5a.large
- Number of instances: 2
- Storage: 20 GB General Purpose SSD, Delete storage on termination
- Tags: Name=lfs258_class
- Allow all traffic from everywhere
- Use the existing SSH Keypair I have on my laptop

This is the tree file structure

```
.
├── README.md
├── ec2.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── provider.tf
├── variables.tf
└── versions.tf
```

**file ec2.tf**

```
locals {
  availability_zone = "${local.region}a"
  name              = "kubernetes-lfs258-course"
  region            = "us-east-1"
  tags = {
    Owner       = "pss-cli-user1 "
    Environment = "kubernetes-lfs258-course"
  }
}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"
  name = local.name
  azs              = ["${local.region}a", "${local.region}b", "${local.region}c"]
  public_subnets   = lookup(var.init,"public-subnet")
  tags = local.tags
}

module "security_group" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "~> 4.0"
  name        = local.name
  description = "Security group for example usage with EC2 instance"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  ingress_rules       = ["all-all"]
  egress_rules        = ["all-all"]
  tags = local.tags
}


################################################################################
# Supporting Resources for the EC2 module
################################################################################


module "ec2" {
  source = "../../"

  name = local.name

  ami                         = lookup(var.init,"ami")
  #instance_type               = "c5.large"
  instance_type               = lookup(element(var.instances,0),"instance_type")
  availability_zone           = local.availability_zone
  subnet_id                   = element(module.vpc.private_subnets, 0)
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [module.security_group.security_group_id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  tags = local.tags
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "this" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.this.id
  instance_id = module.ec2.id
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "this" {
  availability_zone = local.availability_zone
  size              = 20
  tags = local.tags
}
```

**file outputs.tf**

```
# EC2
output "ec2_id" {
  description = "The ID of the instance"
  value       = module.ec2.id
}

output "ec2_arn" {
  description = "The ARN of the instance"
  value       = module.ec2.arn
}

output "ec2_capacity_reservation_specification" {
  description = "Capacity reservation specification of the instance"
  value       = module.ec2.capacity_reservation_specification
}

output "ec2_instance_state" {
  description = "The state of the instance. One of: `pending`, `running`, `shutting-down`, `terminated`, `stopping`, `stopped`"
  value       = module.ec2.instance_state
}

output "ec2_primary_network_interface_id" {
  description = "The ID of the instance's primary network interface"
  value       = module.ec2.primary_network_interface_id
}

output "ec2_private_dns" {
  description = "The private DNS name assigned to the instance. Can only be used inside the Amazon EC2, and only available if you've enabled DNS hostnames for your VPC"
  value       = module.ec2.private_dns
}

output "ec2_public_dns" {
  description = "The public DNS name assigned to the instance. For EC2-VPC, this is only available if you've enabled DNS hostnames for your VPC"
  value       = module.ec2.public_dns
}

output "ec2_public_ip" {
  description = "The public IP address assigned to the instance, if applicable. NOTE: If you are using an aws_eip with your instance, you should refer to the EIP's address directly and not use `public_ip` as this field will change after the EIP is attached"
  value       = module.ec2.public_ip
}

output "ec2_tags_all" {
  description = "A map of tags assigned to the resource, including those inherited from the provider default_tags configuration block"
  value       = module.ec2.tags_all
}
```

**file provider. tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = local.region
  profile                 = "pss-cli-user1"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
}
```

**file variables.tf**

```
# This file defines variables types and their initial hardcoded values

variable "zones" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"]
}

variable "instances" {
    type = list(object({
    instance_type  = string
    count = number
    tags  = map(string)
    }))

    # If instances is not defined in terraforms.tfvars use this value
    default = [
      {
        instance_type  = "m5a.large"
        count = 2
        tags  = { "UsedFor" = "kubernetes lfs258 course"}
      }
    ]
}


variable "init" {
    type = object({
                    vpc-id=list(string),
                    public-subnet=list(string),
                    aws_region=string,
                    ami=string
                    vpc-sec-group= list(string)
            })

    # if not defined in terraform.tfvars takes this default
    default = {
        vpc-id = ["vpc-02938578"]
        public-subnet = ["subnet-94e25d9a"]
        aws_region = "us-east-1"
        ami = "ami-0747bdcabd34c712a"
        vpc-sec-group = ["sg-d60bf3f5"]
    }
}
```

**file versions.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.1"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 3.51"
    }
  }
}
```

The command `terraform init` works without errors
However `terraform plan` is giving me the following complains

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on ec2.tf line 41, in module "ec2":
│   41:   name = local.name
│ 
│ An argument named "name" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on ec2.tf line 43, in module "ec2":
│   43:   ami                         = lookup(var.init,"ami")
│ 
│ An argument named "ami" is not expected here.

..... more errors like this removed
```

Questions are :

- What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?
- How to create a better IaC Terraform deployment?

BR
David

Comment: Your `ec2` module doesn't have a `name` variable defined so Terraform is erroring when you attempt to pass a `name` parameter to it.

Comment: I thought that ``` module "ec2" { .... name = local.name } ``` defined the name varible on the ec2 module

Comment: No that's passing `local.name` to the module's `name` variable. If you haven't defined it then it will fail. Think of it like a normal programming language with a method that only takes keyword args. If you pass it a keyword arg that isn't in the method signature then it will error.